# Linq to Entities: How can i filter in the where clause on fields from a derived type (Table per Type inheritance)?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am working on a risk monitoring application with a SQL DB in the background. I use EF 4 Database First. There is a "Position" class in the model, which models holdings in various types of assets. A position holds a reference to a "Contract" class. This "Contract" class serves as the base class for various types of financial contracts, such as "Investment".

The classes look as follows:

```
    public class Position
    {
       public int ContractID {get;set;}            
       public DateTime PositionDate {get;set;}
       public decimal MarketValue {get;set;}
    }

    public class Contract
    {
       public int ID {get;set;}
       public string Description {get;set;}
       public int CurrencyID {get;set;}
       public Instrument Instruments {get;set;}

    }

    public class Investment:Contract
    {
       public int ID {get;set;}
       public int BBGIndustryID {get;set;}
    }
```

When i try to run a query and try to filter on properties from the "Investment" Class, the system throws an StackOverFlowException:

```
var dataPoint = _context.Positions.Where(c => c.Contract.Instruments != null).Where(c => c.Contract.Instruments.BBGIndustryID == 24).ToList();
```

How do i need to write the query that i can filter on properties from the derived classes, or do i need to move the properties i need to filter on to move to the base class?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please add more detail of your model, eg, what properties have Contract and what properties have Investment?

Comment: Hi octavioccl, i have added the three classes with the relevant properties.

Comment: Try to remove the part `.Where(c => c.Contract.Instruments != null)`. It is not necessary because the whole statement is translated into SQL.

Comment: I tried without it, it still gives me an StackOverflowexception